# swap function in quick sort gives wrong output

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

swap function for quick sort. It gives wrong output. when i use temporary variable it gives the correct output.
Here is the tester:

```
void swap(int &a,int &b){
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a-b;
}
```

this works fine though:

```
void swap(int &a,int &b){
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=a;
}
```

I am passing array elements to this function inside the partition function of quick sort algorithm.

Comment: When you say "temporary variable" can you elaborate on that? Because references can't bind to temporary variables. That will lead to *undefined behavior*, which could lead to such behavior you see. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide context. What do you pass to get correct or incorrect result?

Comment: One problem with your type of swap is it can underflow or overflow which is undefined behavior.  if you need a swap function just use `std::swap` and trust that the library implementer knows what they are doing.

Comment: It isn't even useful. Swapping through a temporary variable is faster.

Answer (score 7):

Your code for swap without the 3rd variable looks ok. Unfortunately, this algorithm cannot be applied for swapping a value with itself, for example:

```
void swap(int &a,int &b){   // &a == &b, the value is 123
    a=a+b;                  // a == b == 246
    b=a-b;                  // a == b == 0 (Oops!)
    a=a-b;                  // a == b == 0 
}
```

Also, please note that there's a standard function for swapping (`std::swap`) and that your code, if compiled without optimization, works slower than the usual swap (with 3rd variable) as it performs more memory operations. Also, this code may lead to integer overflow or underflow which is undefined behavior by the standard and may or may not work as you expect. If we add readability issue (the most important thing) to this list, the recommendation is **just don't use swap without 3rd variable**.

Comment: Unfortunately neither GCC nor Clang optimize this to the same thing as a normal swap, so it's just simply worse. Maybe they'll do it someday..

Comment: @harold Thanks for correcting, will fix in the answer text

Comment: why is that &a==&b? they are pointing to different variables.So how can they be equal?

Comment: @PranaySaraiwala `swap` should not set the value to `0` when called to swap the value with itself. Some of the easiest implementation of quicksort may swap the element with itself.

Comment: `thank you!!! that was really helpful` - instead of amassing exclamation marks (see Terry Pratchett on the topic), consider accepting an answer.